# Sklearn Logistical Regression coef_ giving list of lists

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

The goal of this program is to predict the number of stars from a number of features in a github repo.

This works fine, good accuracy, now what I want, is to find the feature importance of these features. I see the coef_ being used a lot for this as it seems a simple solution.

The issue I am having is that coef_ returns a lis of lists 3x10 (10 being the number of features as seen below)

My question is, why are 3 different lists returned?

```
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', multi_class='ovr', max_iter=1000)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

For reference, X_train is shape 5000x10 and Y_train shape 5000x1

**Features**

Being predicted is a column **overTwentyFivePercent**

```
pd.DataFrame(model.coef_[0], dfCopy.columns, columns=['coefficient'])

name             -0.145628
pushed_at        -0.052148
updated_at        1.100940
size             -0.006121
has_downloads    -0.084252
watchers         16.291155
open_issues      -0.029331
forks             0.901897
created_at       -0.020457
archived         -0.081115
```

**Resulting list**

```
importance = model.coef_

[[-1.40184146e-01 -4.84178243e-02  1.15512242e+00 -3.28964506e-02
  -6.26576200e-02  1.62359829e+01 -1.15330585e-02  8.69313030e-01
  -1.98661071e-02 -6.42662896e-02]
 [ 1.94129222e-02 -7.45851193e-03  2.73873650e-01 -1.36233707e-02
   2.02166947e-02 -3.34864880e+00 -2.68649386e-02 -6.72242010e-02
  -2.37043006e-02 -7.86084337e-03]
 [ 1.99005178e-02  1.94243453e-02 -1.27329344e-01  5.62809134e-02
  -1.26026931e-02 -2.04670813e+01 -9.90259533e-02 -2.51335991e+00
  -3.91467209e-02  3.87512897e-02]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), `coefs_` has shape `(n_classes, n_features)`, which suggests that you have somehow fitted the model to have three classes.  Check the unique values in `Y_train`, or `model.classes_`.